# constrain using two one to many relations in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I want to constrain using two one to many relations using Laravel Eloquent; when adding the second constraint as a method the error states the query is being run in reverse to what I actually need and I am not experienced enough with Laravel yet to know why this is happening.

```
 class YeargroupController extends Controller
    {
        public function index($id)     
        {      
            $yeargroups = Yeargroup::get();
            $objectives = Yeargroup::find(1)->objectives->where('subject_id',$id);
            
            return view('admin.yeargroups.index',[
                'yeargroups' => Yeargroup::with('objectives.subjects')->get(),
            ],compact('objectives','yeargroups'));
        }
    }
```

MODELS

```
class Objective extends Model
{
    
     public function subjects() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Subject');
    }
     
    public function yeargroups()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Yeargroup');
    }
}

class Subject extends Model
{

    public function objectives() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Objective');
    }
}

class Yeargroup extends Model
{
    
    public function objectives()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Objective');
    }
}
```

ERROR

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'subjects.objective_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `subjects` where `subjects`.`objective_id` in (1, 2) and `subjects`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Objective models like this:

```
class Objective extends Model
{
    
     public function subjects() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Subject');
    }
     
    public function yeargroups()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Yeargroup');
    }
}
```

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: this no longer errors, thank you. however I am not quite getting the return that I need. I need to now constrain by the subject id, instead I am seeing objectives from all subjects.

Comment: Base on what data you need, change the `with()`
From:
`'yeargroups' => Yeargroup::with('objectives.subjects')->get()`
To:
`'yeargroups' => Yeargroup::with('objectives')->get()`